# Solvable equivalent to nilpotency of first derived Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, solvable-groups

The Wikipedia ["Solvable Lie Algebra"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_Lie_algebra) page lists the following property as a notion equivalent to solvability: $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable iff the first derived algebra $[\mathfrak{g},\,\mathfrak{g}]$ is nilpotent.

I can't see this at all and it does sound dodgy: solvability and nilpotency different by "only one rung" in the derived series. Is this correct (I suspect I'm missing something trivial- I can't seem to find anything relevant in Knapp "Lie Groups: Beyond an Introduction" (mine is reprint of the first edition))? If not universally correct, is it correct with further assumptions about the field which $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space over? (For example, a field of characteristic nought, algebraically closed, ...). Can someone either give a proof, a counterexample or a reference to one?

I'd also like to put a reference on the Wikipedia page quotation, or clearly have it stricken from the page if incorrect.

Comment: This is not true in general, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886950/let-l-be-a-lie-algebra-why-if-l-be-supersolvable-then-l-l-l). A counterexample is given in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras. It is true, though, over algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Many thanks. I don't have Jacobson's book so I'll need to look it up when I'm next in a university library (I'm not an academic). You seem to imply Quiochu Yuan's reasoning isn't quite right below: i.e. one thinks of the algebra as an algebra of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{K})$ matrices with elements in field $\mathbb{K}$ as special cases of $\mathcal{M}(\bar{\mathbb{K}})$  matrices with elements in the alg. closure $\bar{\mathbb{K}}$, find simulaneous upper triangularizing matrix in $T\in \mathcal{M}(\bar{\mathbb{K}})$ by Lie's theorem to argue that the  transformed algebras .....

Comment: @DietrichBurde .... $T\,\mathfrak{g}\,T^{-1}\subset \mathcal{M}(\bar{\mathbb{K}})$ and $T\,[\mathfrak{g},\,\mathfrak{g}]\,T^{-1}\subset\mathcal{M}(\bar{\mathbb{K}})$ have the claimed relationship, then transform back to the algebra of matrices in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{K})$ and the structure constants of the Lie algebra are unchanged by the inverse conjugation by $T^{-1}$, so the original algebras have the same properties and relationships. PS Of course I assume $\mathbb{K}$ has characteristic 0. Or am I missing something? I also see very clearly that it isn't true in general: I didn't think...

Comment: @DietrichBurde ... to use Lie's theorem and was instead simply assuming that the claim was meant to follow from the definitions, but the analogue for groups certainly isn't true (first derived group isn't in general nilpotent).

Comment: I only wanted to say that there are counterexamples in characteristic $p>0$. The answer of Qiaochu Yuan is perfectly right. He just says "I don't think this is true in general", and here we have indeed counterexamples.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks: I was just checking the algebraic closure was not necessary.

Comment: I should add that for every given dimension $n$ there exists $p_0$ such that every $n$-dimensional solvable Lie algebra of characteristic $p\ge p_0$ and dimension $n$ has nilpotent derived subalgebra. For if we have a sequence of counterexamples, they are all of bounded derived length $(\le n)$, hence taking an ultraproduct we have a Lie algebra in char. zero that is solvable and whose derived subalgebra is, say, not $n$-nilpotent, and hence is not nilpotent since the dimension is $\le n$, contradiction. Probably a careful explicit proof of the char zero case yields an explicit bound on $p_0$

Comment: @YCor That sounds like an interesting paper to write! Is this bound not known?

Comment: I think it's suitable for here :) I'd first check if the char 0 proof yields a bound (working in a alg. closed field of char $p$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia says, correctly, that this is equivalent if $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite-dimensional over a field of characteristic zero. I don't think it's true in general.

The hard direction is to show that this condition holds if $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable. Here's a sketch. Since the image $\text{ad}[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ of $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ differs from it by a central extension, it suffices to show that $\text{ad}[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ is nilpotent. By [Lie's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%E2%80%93Kolchin_theorem#Lie.27s_theorem), over an algebraic closure $\bar{k}$ of the ground field the elements of $\text{ad}(\mathfrak{g})$ are simultaneously upper triangularizable. It follows that over $\bar{k}$ the elements of $\text{ad}[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ can be represented by strictly upper triangular matrices, and hence $\text{ad} [\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ is nilpotent over $\bar{k}$. But nilpotence just means that certain words vanish identically, and whether this is true doesn't depend on whether we extend the ground field or not; hence $\text{ad}[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$ is nilpotent.

Comment: As for a reference, this should be in any sensible textbook!

Comment: For example, it is Proposition 1.39 in Knapp's *Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction* (although I don't know what book of Knapp's the OP has in mind).

Comment: Indeed. Lie's theorem gives you a flag of ideals in the adjoint rep which the rep preserves, and elements in the derived subalgebra push things one level deeper.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez that's a nice statement of a proof sketch: instantly graspable. Commutators of upper triangulars are strictly upper triangular and the latter form a Lie subalgebra qed. I was missing something trivial, as I suspected.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Many thanks.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I especially like your last sentence: nice addition to exclude need for algebraic closure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, which edition of Knapp do you have? I take it yours must be the second edition; mine is a recent softcover reprint of supposedly the first edition, where (1.39) isn't a proposition.

Comment: @WetSavanna: second edition.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple proof that there exists, over any field, a solvable Lie algebra (of infinite dimension) whose derived subalgebra is non-nilpotent.

Consider the free complex class-3 solvable Lie algebra on countably many generators. Suppose by contradiction that its derived subalgebra is nilpotent, say $c$-nilpotent. Then from the universal property it follows that every countably generated (in part., every finite-dimensional) 3-solvable Lie algebra has a $c$-nilpotent derived subalgebra. We then get a contradiction as follows: for $n\ge 2$, let $\mathfrak{h}_n$ be the Lie algebra with basis $(e_1,f_1,\dots,f_{n-1})$ and nonzero brackets $[e_1,f_i]=e_{i+1}$ for $1\le i\le n-2$. Let $D$ be the derivation of this Lie algebra given by $e_1\mapsto e_1$, $f_i\mapsto if_i$, and consider the corresponding (2-solvable) semidirect product $\mathfrak{g}_n=\mathfrak{a}_1\ltimes_{D}\mathfrak{h}_n$, where $\mathfrak{a}_n$ is 1-dimensional abelian. Note that $[\mathfrak{h}_n,\mathfrak{h}_n]$ is abelian, so that $\mathfrak{g}_n$ is 3-solvable. Also $[\mathfrak{g}_n,\mathfrak{g}_n]=\mathfrak{h}_n$ (regardless of the characteristic), whose nilpotency class is exactly $n-1$. Since $n$ is unbounded, this yields contradiction and actually the free complex class-3 solvable Lie algebra has its derived subalgebra non-nilpotent.

(Alternatively, to avoid invoking free objects/ universal properties, the product $\prod_n\mathfrak{g}_n$ (or the restricted product if you like) is 3-solvable and its derived subalgebra is non-nilpotent).

---

Edit: here's a variant, yielding a finitely generated algebra.

Consider the free metabelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{k}$ on two generators $x,y$ (over any field). It is naturally graded in $\mathbf{Z}^2$ with $x$ of degree $(1,0)$ and $y$ of degree $(0,1)$. It is not nilpotent (because it admits the standard filiform $n$-dimensional algebra as a a quotient for every $n$, and the latter has a nontrivial $(n-1)$-th term of the central series). Consider the commuting derivations $D,E$ of $\mathfrak{f}$ where $D$ (resp. $E$) acts by multiplication by $i$ (resp. $j$) on $\mathfrak{f}_{(i,j)}$

The semidirect product of $\mathfrak{f}$ by a 2-dimensional abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ acting on $\mathfrak{f}$ by $D$ and $E$ has $\mathfrak{f}$ as derived subalgebra, which is not nilpotent. It is finitely generated as it is generated by the 4-dimensional subspace $\mathfrak{a}\oplus\mathfrak{f}_{(1,0)}\oplus\mathfrak{f}_{(0,1)}$.

Comment: Not what I was thinking of (I was thinking mainly finite dimensional - but didn't make this clear, so my bad) but extremely interesting and enlightening: fantastic to see explicitly how countably infinite dimension exactly breaks the other arguments. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a counterexample given in Jacobsons book, i.e., an example of a finite-dimensional solvable Lie algebra $L$ in characteristic $p>0$ such that $[L,L]$ is not nilpotent.
More concretely, this Lie algebra $L$ has a basis $(x,y,e_1,\ldots ,e_p)$ with Lie brackets
\begin{align*}
[x,y]   & = x, \\
[x,e_1] & = e_p, \\
[x,e_i] & = e_{i-1}, \; i\ge 2,\\
[y,e_i] & = (i-1)e_i, \; 1\le i\le p.
\end{align*}
Since $V=\operatorname{span}(e_1,\ldots ,e_p)$ is solvable (even abelian) and the quotient $L/V$ is solvable, so is $L$. But $[L,L]=kx\oplus V$ is not nilpotent.
We have $[L,L]^1=[L,L]^2=\cdots =V$.