# Doubt about nilpotency of the derived algebra of a Leibniz algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I want to proof:

"Let $(L,[\cdot,\cdot])$ be a (right or left) Leibniz algebra. If $[L,L]$ is nilpotent then $L$ is solvable".

I know that a similar result is posted for Lie algebras. But here we get a more general context with the Leibniz algebras.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not even true for Lie algebras, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304877/solvable-equivalent-to-nilpotency-of-first-derived-lie-algebra).

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for finite-dimensional algebras over a field of characteristic zero. It follows from a weak version of Lie's Theorem for Leibniz algebras, see Corollary $6$ in the paper [On some basic properties of Leibniz algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3345) by V. Gorbatsevich.